# sed conditional replace of a variable

Tags: regex, sed

I have within a file a bunch of codenumbers that in general are of the form, integer.integer The first integer is necessary, the second may be empty. e.g. 123.45 or 12.345 and 12 are all valid codenumbers.

I want to use sed to change each of these lines into

```
job{123}subjob{45}
job{12}subjob{345}
job{12}
```

So far I have

```
sed -e 's/codenumber{\([0-9]*\)\.*\([0-9]*\)}/job{\1}subjob{\2}/g'
```

which results in

```
job{123}subjob{45}
job{12}subjob{345}
job{12}subjob{}
```

Is there a way for sed to realise that when the variable \2 is empty, to print a default value instead, say 0. Hence the last line of the given example would say

```
job{12}subjob{0}
```

I suppose this could be possible via two sed runs, but I am interested if it was possible with one.

Comment: Are leading zeros a problem (except for being redundant)? If all else fails you could just always write a 0 after your opening bracket.

Comment: I like this, (it works too in my application) but I was looking for something that I could also generalise.

Comment: Why is there a superfluous `*` after the dot: `\.*` in that regex? There can only be one dot between two numbers right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply extend your `sed` command to patch up empty subjob numbers:

```
sed -e 's/codenumber{\([0-9]*\)\.*\([0-9]*\)}/job{\1}subjob{\2}/g' \
    -e 's/subjob{}/subjob{0}/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in sed. But indeed you can do two sed runs (they're really fast so it shouldn't be a problem), the second being

```
sed -e 's/subjob\{\}//g'
```

Comment: It can definitely be done in a single `sed` run; there are many possible ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/codenumber/job/;s/\./}subjob{/;/subjob/!s/$/subjob{0}/' file
```

Comment: yes it does: `echo -e 'codenumber{123.45}\ncodenumber{12.345}\ncodenumber{12}' | sed -e 's/codenumber/job/;s/\./}subjob{/;/subjob/!s/$/subjob{0}/'`

Answer (score 0):

I know, a bit too late and in addition not answering the question, but if someone lands here as I did, and does not mind to use Perl instead, so the expression is:

```
s/codenumber{([0-9]*)\.*([0-9]*)}/job{$1}subjob{${\($2?$2:"0")}}/g
```

e.g. in:

```
echo -e 'codenumber{123.45}\ncodenumber{12.345}\ncodenumber{12}' | perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { print s/codenumber{([0-9]*)\.*([0-9]*)}/job{$1}subjob{${\($2?$2:"0")}}/gr;}'
```

So, the point is that Perl allows you to use the string interpolation `${\(EXPRESSION)}` also in the regexp and calculate the replacement, based on the matched value, using a Perl expression.